# iframe onclick not working in chrome but working fine in firefox

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.addEventListener("click", function() {
     alert("in contentWindow event")}, false);
});
```

where **id** is id of my iframe. Alert is coming in firefox but not in chrome.
Can anybody suggest why this is not working or any alternative??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect click inside iframe (same domain/sub domain) in Chrome using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477917/detect-click-inside-iframe-same-domain-sub-domain-in-chrome-using-jquery)

Comment: Some browsers may block the alerts . Try using some ajax to interact with your server code and make a console log.

Comment: I also faced the same and and solved by confirm by onclick works.