# Getting parent value in an iframe gives permission denied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below two html files in two different web applications. `WebApp1(somedomain.com)` has `PassValueIFrame.html` and `WebApp2` has `inputForm.html`. `Here WebApp1 is secured and requires authentication`. In `PassValueIFrame.html`  i have an iframe which refers `inputForm.html`. Also, i have one hidden field in `PassValueIFrame.html` and am trying to retrieve its value in `inputForm.html` but am not getting its value it alerts as '`Permission denied to access property 'document'`'. Am i doing any wrong here? Please help me. As `WenbApp1` is secured, cannot we access `PassValueIFrame.html` ? if we cannot access then is there any way to access secured page contents?

### PassValueIFrame.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>IFrame Example</title>
  </head>
<body>
<input id="myInput" type="hidden" class="Language" value="English">
<iframe name="iframe" id="iframe_id" src="http://somedomain.com/inputForm.html" height="150" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

### inputForm.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#myInput", window.parent.document).val());
  });

  </script>
   <title>IFrame Child Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Iframeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee </h1>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cross-Domain Scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be violating the same origin policy restriction. You cannot access the iframe contents if both the parent and the iframe are hosted on the same domain. So basically if you want this to work you will have to host `PassValueIFrame.html` on `http://somedomain.com`.

Comment: u mean both the web applications should be hosted on same application server?

Comment: right now my WebApp1 is in AppserverOne and WebApp2 is in AppServerTwo. To get it working, i have to deploy WebApp1 and WebApp2 in AppserverOne right? Please correct me...

Comment: it doesn't matter on which server(s) you have deployed your application onto. All that matters is that their websites have binding on the same domain. So you should have `http://somedomain.com/PassValueIFrame.html` and `http://somedomain.com/inputForm.html`.

Comment: oh..Thanx for clarifying..if i have http://abc.com/PassValueIFrame.html and http://xyz.com/inputForm.html then it is not possible to access...am i right now?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Darin, Thanx for clarifying..Then is there any alternative for my problem? Please help me!

Comment: Yes, you could use `postMessage`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652646/how-to-properly-use-postmessage-to-do-cross-domain-messaging-with-html5-and-mode But of course this is only supported on modern browsers only.

Comment: Also, i have http://abc.com/WebApp1/PassValueIFrame.html and http://abc.com/WebApp2/inputForm.html. Then i can access right? there will not be any cross domain scripting issues right?

Comment: "You cannot access the iframe contents if both the parent and the iframe are hosted on the same domain" - Do you mean different domains?